# Cannot create IOS App Development provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting this error (see image below).
My Apple ID account has not been enrolled in a developer program. Would I need to do that in order to get rid of the error?

Anything else that can be causing this error?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of your project enable the **Push Notification**, that need the developer certificate.

You can simple disable it in

> Project File > Target > Capabilities > Turn off the Push Notification

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 6):

Answer depends on what is your requirement.

- Need to just get rid of the error. Then just disable the push notifications in the capabilities tab in the project.
- Need to run on device or create an IPA or your app needs support for push notifications then you need to enroll to Apple developer account and create the required certificates & provisioning profiles to proceed further.

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened to me when I created a new app listing in and Apple made me connect it to an existing app certificate. I manually created and selected it which was the mistake (instead of doing it via xCode)

The solution was to:

1. Change the namespace on XCode temporarily so it will accept it. ("example.nsTemp")
2. Go to the App Store Connect -> Your New App -> App Information
3. Choose the newly created temporary bundle name ("example.nsTemp")
4. Go to the "Identifiers" in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list and delete your original app identifies which you would like to use ("example.nsOriginal")
5. Go back to XCode, rename to the deleted namespace ("example.nsOriginal")
6. Go to the App Store Connect -> Your New App -> App Information and choose the original

Drink water.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should remove Apple signin capability